# Network Manager in ubuntu 18.04 crashes and I've to reboot everytime

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, crash, reboot

I use ubuntu 18.04 and the wireless crashes in every 1 hour. The network setting says the network manager is not running.
How to resolve this?

I tried **sudo service network-manager restart**, but the terminal also hangs.

Answer (score -1):

try below commands

```
pkill nm-applet && nm-applet &
```

Comment: Why? What are you expecting to happen differently than the restart command the OP used?